# What is the maximum number of highlighted numbers we see on the board?

Tags: combinatorics

There are 10 different numbers and if there is a number that is equal to the product of the other 9 numbers it is highlighted. What is the maximum number of highlighted numbers we see on the board?

Comment: All numbers could be equal to $0$. Or equal to $1$. In such a case, you have 10 highlighted numbers.

Comment: different numbers

Comment: Are these numbers natural numbers? Integers? Non-negative? Complex? The answer depends on the kind of numbers.

Comment: The problem originally says "numbers", so I think they can be everything, but it's for 9-10th grade which can help (for example, we are not supposed to have studied complex numbers yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem can be found [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-maximum-number-of-highlighted-numbers-we-see-on-the-board)